# How to validate data in django forms?

Tags: django, forms, django-models, email-validation

I have a feature on my website where a user can share content with another user registered on the site. They do this by entering in an email belonging to another user. This is then posted, setting the desired user to as a shared owner of content in the model.

What is the best way to check that the email address belongs to a registered user of the site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the efficient way is to search for the user with the given mail. Django User already has a mail field that is unique.

if you want to write from basic:

```
from django.core.validators import validate_email

class SampleForm(forms.Form):
    mail = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SampleForm, self).clean()
        mail = cleaned_data.get('mail')
        # validate the structure of the mail address
        try:
            validate_email(mail)
        except validate_email.ValidationError:
            raise forms.ValidationError('email is not valid')
        # now find if mail has registered
        try:
            User.objects.get(email=mail)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError('This mail address is not registered')
        return cleaned_data
```